# How to reduce the k-coloring to k-coloring with constraint?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

By here the constraint means the number of nodes in one color cannot exceeds a certain number.

Comment: This question should be asked in [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just set the constraint ```number of nodes in one color cannot exceed a certain number``` to the number of nodes. If that's not the answer, than your question is formulated wrong (at least regarding reduction-orientation).